# Can company-mode show the doc of the functions?

Tags: jedi, company

I am using [`company-mode`](http://company-mode.github.io) for backends to auto-complete in Python and `emacs` is used as command line.

```
(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'global-company-mode)
(setq company-auto-complete t)

(setq company-auto-complete t)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-k") 'company-complete)
```

During autocompletion, it shows the name of the fuctions and their type. In addition to those, I was wondering can it show the `doc` of the each function like `jedi` does (example first image on the [jedi site](https://tkf.github.io/emacs-jedi/latest/))?

---

`company` (information of functions are missing on the right hand-side):

[image]

`jedi`:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default company-mode doesn't seems to have that feature, BUT there is a package called [company-box](https://github.com/sebastiencs/company-box) that take care of the documentation among other things:

- **Without** company-box:
  [image]
- **With** company-box:
  [image]

(To trigger the doc, you may have to wait like a second)

Comment: I have installed `company-box` but nothing happens :-( // should I add any line into `.emacs` file

Comment: Did you follow https://github.com/sebastiencs/company-box#installation ?
If it is the case, some functions may not have documentation, or it may take some time to load (also point out that you have to scroll throw the company suggestion list, even if it is the first result, this can be done with company-select-next). 
If still doesn't work.. it may be something to do with your config or other package

Comment: Yes but I haven't done any additional configuration. Also I am using emacs in the terminal. Seems like it is not compatible with terminal CLI

Comment: Right! sorry about that, I'm not using Emacs in the command line, but yeah, according to the author it doesn't work in the terminal (https://github.com/sebastiencs/company-box/issues/103)

Comment: Ah :-( is there any alternative package ?

Comment: Oh! seems like there is, sorry but I didn't knew it (maybe I change my company-box) https://github.com/company-mode/company-quickhelp ,and it works in the terminal!

Comment: ah still does not work :( seems like something is overwriting on my .emacs file

Comment: A while ago, but are you still using this and do icons still show in the company candidates with company-box installed?